# How to make bold a particular word that has #bold word Jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi there is there a way to make a particular text bold for example

> I have this #boldword and I want #boldword2  this two to be bold like this.
>
> I have this **word** and I want **word2**  this two to be bold like this.

So as you can see the second example I want every word that has bold in front to become bold and the #bold to be removed.

I tried something so far

```js
$.fn.wrapInTag = function(opts) {

  var tag = opts.tag || 'strong',
    words = opts.words || [],
    regex = RegExp(words.join('|'), 'gi'),
    replacement = '<strong>$&</strong>';

  return this.html(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(regex, replacement);
  });
};

$('p').wrapInTag({
  tag: 'em',
  words: ['#boldworld']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>The #boldworld is big and red.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you have a list of words you want **bold**ing, which contain the prefix `#bold`. You want to remove the `#bold` prefix from your words?

All you need to do is add `.replace('#bold', '')` to your text.

#### Edit

Based on your comment, you want to change the regex so it matches **any** string that starts with `#bold` and embolden it?

The pattern I am using is `(#bold([^\s\.]+))` - find any word beginning with `#bold` then capture everything up until a space or period `([^\s\.]+)`. The reason why the whole lot is in parenthesis is so that the whole string gets replaced. I've also changed the replacement string from `$&` to `$2`. The difference is, [`$&` is similar to `$1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34510780/351785), in that it will place the whole matched string (e.g. `#boldworld`) into the text; while `$2` will put in the inner matched text (i.e. what it matches in `([^\s\.]+)`, e.g. `world`).

For my own sanity, I've also removed the jquery call from the inner function and replaced it with vanilla javascript.

```js
"use strict";
$.fn.wrapInTag = function() {
  //this = jQuery element
  return this.html(function() {
    //this = dom element
    return this.textContent
               .replace(/(#bold([^\s\.]+))/gi, '<strong>$2</strong>');
  });

};

$('p').wrapInTag();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>The #boldworld is big and #boldred.</p>
```

Comment: "*every word that has bold in front*" - ie change "red" to "#boldred" and it should also be be bold "**red**".  There shouldn't be a list of words.

Comment: How can I make to search the text that comes from db  for every word that has #bold in front

Comment: Updated answer.