# Regex filter returning object Object instead of element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I am using React and external API

I am receiving data from an external api that has urls throughout it,
i.e.

```
sampleText = Ethereum’s original token distribution event, managed by the [Ethereum Foundation](https://messari.io/asset/ethereum)
```

I want to turn the urls into links using:

```
 const turnIntoLink =(text)=>{
    const urlFilter = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gi;
    return text.replace(urlFilter, (url)=>{
      return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + "</a>";
    })
  }
turnIntoLink(sampleText)
```

when i use the above code it properly reads the urls but returns

```
... managed by the [Ethereum Foundation](<a href="https://messari.io/asset/ethereum">https://messari.io/asset/ethereum</a>)
```

when I change turnIntoLink to this

```
 const turnIntoLink =(text)=>{
    const urlFilter = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gi;
    return text.replace(urlFilter, (url)=>{
      return <a href={url}>${url}</a>;
    })
  }
```

it returns

```
... managed by the [Ethereum Foundation]([object Object])
```

updated CoinDetail.jsx reflecting use of backreference

```
import React from "react";

const CoinDetail = (props) => {
  const { profile } = props.details;
  const turnIntoLink = (text) => {
    const urlFilter = /\[([^\][]*)]\(((?:https?|ftps?|file):\/\/[^()]*)\)/gi;
    return text.replace(urlFilter, '<a href="$2">$1</a>');
  };
  const display = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          Launch Details:
          {turnIntoLink(profile.economics.launch.general.launch_details)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
  return <section>{profile ? display() : "Loading"}</section>;
};

export default CoinDetail;
```

How can i get it to return an actual a element?

Update:

I was able to get it to work by doing this below in the return

```
   <span
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: turnIntoLink(
                profile.economics.launch.general.launch_details
              ),
            }}
          ></span>
```

It works but i feel like this is kinda hacky and theres a better way to do this. IS there?

Comment: You do not need to use a callback as a replacement argument when you need [to replace with the whole match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510746/difference-between-1-and-in-regular-expressions/34510780#34510780). There is a `$&` backreference.

Comment: The only way I know is to split and join the string while converting the parts into the right JSX when needed. Unfortunately, I cannot find a reference to this approach.

Comment: What about https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace? This will enable you to write `return ( <div>  {reactStringReplace(content, /\[([^\][]*)]\(((?:https?|ftps?|file):\/\/[^()]*)\)/gi, (match, x, y) => (  <a href={y}>{x}</a>  ))}  </div>`

Answer (score 2):

In **React**, you can use the following code with [**React String Replace**](https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace):

```js
return (
 <div>
   {reactStringReplace(content, /\[([^\][]*)]\(((?:https?|ftps?|file):\/\/[^()]*)\)/gi, (match, x, y) => (  <a href={y}>{x}</a>  ))}
 </div>
```

If you are using plain JavaScript, you can use

```js
const turnIntoLink = (text) => {
    const urlFilter = /\[([^\][]*)]\(((?:https?|ftps?|file):\/\/[^()]*)\)/gi;
    return text.replace(urlFilter, '<a href="$2">$1</a>');
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZmcCOe/1/). *Details*:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^\][]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]\(` - `](` string
- `((?:https?|ftps?|file):\/\/[^()]*)` - Group 2: `http`, `https`, `ftp`, `ftps`, `file` and then a `://` substring and then any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const turnIntoLink = (text) => {
    const urlFilter = /\[([^\][]*)]\(((?:https?|ftps?|file):\/\/[^()]*)\)/gi;
    return text.replace(urlFilter, '<a href="$2">$1</a>');
}

console.log( turnIntoLink("Ethereum’s original token distribution event, managed by the [Ethereum Foundation](https://messari.io/asset/ethereum)") );
```

Comment: I tried your code and it still returned (<a href="https://messari.io/asset/ethereum">https://messari.io/asset/ethereum</a>)

Comment: @JoeCillo **My** code returns `Ethereum’s original token distribution event, managed by the <a href="https://messari.io/asset/ethereum">Ethereum Foundation</a>`, please run *Run code snippet*.

Comment: Yes, sorry it does return that, I copied the wrong text, but it still returning as text and not a link

Comment: @JoeCillo Do you code in React? Please update the question if you do, please also add the relevant code, and if possible, a reproducible code snippet.

Comment: Yes I am using react, I updated the post to reflect that and included the code