# How to use string with regex metacharacters as regex in replaceText?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, escaping, google-docs, re2

I have a bit of code that is searching a `document` for a tag and replacing it with a specific merge field. This code works fine until my tag has a `|` (pipe symbol) in it.

For some reason that makes the search only partially match. I suspect this has something to do with it thinking the variable I am passing is a regEx pattern and not a literal string, but I am unsure how to force it to be treated as a string. I use [`replaceText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement), which  accepts regex as a string.

```
bodyObject.replaceText(Regex<String>, Replacement<String>);
```

I use it like this:

```
bodyObject.replaceText(markup, dataRow[headerIndex]);
```

In the above example markup that equals "{{ tag | directive }}" would cause the partially match.

Comment: Can you just escape all pipes in markup?

Comment: Well evidently your current regex is a hack if it's not working the way you want.

Comment: Is it an option to escape the whole string @user10012? This would work on yours, no need overwriting or modifying the variable `markup`, just escape it once you pass it as parameter. It will look like this `bodyObject.replaceText(markup.replace(/\W/g, "\\$&"), dataRow[headerIndex]);`

Comment: That did work! Can you elaborate as to what that did exactly? I get you just taking everything not considered a word, but I am unclear as to why the multiple \\ and the other characters.

Comment: I posted the same as answer below. Included the reference. @user10012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are expecting the markup to be plain text, you can just escape the whole variable when it is passed as a parameter in `replaceText`. I don't find this breaking anything you have and you won't modify anything else aside from the `replaceText` line.

#### Sample:

```
function escapeString() {
  var bodyObject = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  
  markup = "{{ tag | directive }}";
  
  newString = "<mergeField>";
  // escape any non word character ($& = whole matched string)
  bodyObject.replaceText(markup.replace(/\W/g, "\\$&"), newString);
}
```

#### Before:

[image: sample]

#### After:

[image: after]

#### Reference:

- [Javascript RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping)
- [\\](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-regular-expressions.php)
- [$&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510746/difference-between-1-and-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510746/difference-between-1-and-in-regular-expressions

Comment: Thanks for providing a more comprehensive explanation @Cooper, adding it as reference.

Comment: I think this will break with `{{tag | di\rective}}`

Answer (score 1):

[.replaceText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement) supports [re2](/questions/tagged/re2) and [re2 supports `\Q...\E`](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax):

> \Q...\E literal text ... even if ... has punctuation

So you can use:

```
bodyObject.replaceText(String.raw`\Q${markup}\E`, dataRow[headerIndex]);
```

This will treat everything inside `\Q...\E` as literal characters.